# Working with dates and abline(v) in R

Tags: r, date, plot, scatter

I'm working on a set of scatter plots in R, and I want to add a vertical line to all of them. The x-axis is in Date type, and I think that's the problem for me. When I call

```
abline(v=movie_revenues$X, col="orange")
```

the line does not show up on the plot. The column "X" is the movie's premiere date, in this form: "11-Dec-2011". When I try to cast it as a date using `as.Date()`, it gives me an error saying that the text is in ambiguous form.

From this, I guess there are two points where I could have gone wrong.

1. R doesn't recognize `11-Dec-2011` as a date, but tries to plot it anyway without throwing an error, resulting in a missing vertical line; or,
2. the date is recognized correctly, but I've called abline
   incorrectly, or abline's plotted the line too thin/small for me to
   see (the y-axis on these plots are very large).

I'm new to R, so please let me know if there's anything silly I've missed.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `dmy()`from the package `lubridate` instead of `as.Date()`.

Comment: @majom So I think that should successfully convert into Dates (the error caused by as.Date() doesn't come up anymore), but the abline is still not showing.

Comment: It would help if you could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and would set up an example this way. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when I used the `lubridate` package for BOTH my x-axis and my vertical line. For some reason, when I used `as.Date()` for the x-axis points but `lubridate` for the vertical line coordinate, the line would not appear.